# I want my telegram bot wait until user answers with telebot and callback handler

Tags: python-3.x, telegram, telegram-bot

I am writing a telegram bot with telebot. I have following piece of code:

```
@bot.message_handler(commands=["play"])
def game(message):
    bot.send_message(message.chat.id, 'Start')
    process(message)
    process2(message)

def process(message):
    arr = ['Ans1', 'Ans2', 'Ans3', 'Ans4']
    ans = ['1', '2', '3', '4']
    keyboard = keyboard_gen(arr, ans)
    bot.send_message(message.chat.id, text = 'Question1', reply_markup=keyboard)

def process2(message):
    pass

@bot.callback_query_handler(func=lambda call: True) 
def callback_worker(call):
    if call.data == 1:
        bot.send_message(call.message.chat.id, 'True')
    if call.data in [2, 3, 4]:
        bot.send_message(call.message.chat.id, 'False')
```

keyboard_gen generates keyboards. I need process1 to let user pick right option in process before starting process2. Is there any way to do so? My code immediately starts process2, but I have to be sure user picks right option.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This way of dealing with telegram bots is not recommended. Because each update is a separate request.

You need to use a database to store user's state and reply based on that state.

But here you can move `process2` inside `callback_worker` and call it after the if conditions.

```
@bot.callback_query_handler(func=lambda call: True) 
def callback_worker(call):
    if call.data == 1:
        bot.send_message(call.message.chat.id, 'True')
    if call.data in [2, 3, 4]:
        bot.send_message(call.message.chat.id, 'False')
    process2()
```

Also you should remove `message` parameter from it, if you'd mentioned what you were going to do with `process2()` the solution might have been different.

Check my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60704532/python-telegram-bot-how-to-wait-for-user-answer-to-a-question-and-return-it/60744153#60744153) about storing user `state` in a database.